# Adding Push notification to Exist iOS App

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, app-store-connect

I implemented iOS App and published to the store normally, now I want to make an update to this App by adding Push notification feature. I searched in the net and all the articles that I found talks about how to create a new project contain Push notification, but I need to add an extra feature to my Exist App.

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just update your APP ID and add Push in Member Center then update your application to support push and release an update. No need for more. So you basically do whatever the guides says you need to do but with your existing application.